# How to send an ajax query when the user closes the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, postgresql

I have a problem and I found some solutions but it seems that none of them solve it. I would like to do an ajax query when the user closes the browser. I'm using javascript in the frontend and node in the backend

I tried with window.onbeforeunload and set the query there but it seems that it doesn't work and beforeunload triggers when browser closes but when  the user refreshes the page or closes the tab. I only want to do the query when browser closes.

This is the query that I would like to do:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/getMyInfo',
            data:{},
            success:function(){},
            error:function(){
                data=>{
                var userid=data.data.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/logoutuser",
                    data: userid,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('success logout');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('error logout');
                    }
                });
        }}});
}
```

This doesn't work  even the query is not set.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can detect browser closing vs tab closing. JS shouldn't be aware of what the browser as a whole does, it's usually just given information for the current page (tab). This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You can only detect when the page is unloaded, not when the window is closed.

Comment: VLAZ what I want to do is to send a query when the browse is closed. I thought the solution is similar to what I've posted. Which is the correct way to do this? I can't figure out

Comment: There is no solution. Again, JS doesn't and *shouldn't* have access to the state of the browser. I can't even think of a reason why any page would need to differentiate between a tab, window, or browser closing - they would be similar in all relevant aspects.

Comment: The way I've managed this in the past is by using a websocket to detect the disconnect on the backend then act accordingly. I appreciate this may be an infrastructure change but it may be worth considering.